# How to draw pixels from display buffer?

Tags: qt, qt4, qt4.7, qt4.6, qt4.8

Is there any example Qt code which displays the image from an unsigned char display buffer? Each byte on the buffer corresponds to the Gray scale pixel color. The content of the display buffer changes at run time in specified intervals. I need to change the display buffer content as fast as I can, so that the image seems to be moving. My question is how to draw pixels from the buffer very fast? I don’t need to save the image, just want to display it. Please help

Comment: your questions lacks some corresponding tags while there are lots of unrelated tags being listed in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QImage` provides a [constructor](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qimage.html#QImage-4) for initialization using an `unsigned char` buffer. In order to display it you could use a `QGraphicsView` with a `QGraphicsScene`. Every time the data of the buffer changes you could call a slot similar to the following one:

```
void updateImage()
{
     // I assume an 1024x768 image
     QImage img(buffer, 1024, 768, QImage::Format_Indexed8);
     scene->clear();
     scene->addPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img));
     graphicsView->update(); 
}
```

You could also use the `QPixmap`'s [`loadFromData`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qpixmap.html#loadFromData) in order to load directly the pixmap from the unsigned char array and avoid the `QImage` step.

Comment: I use Qimage instead of QPixmap. But the image shown is always black even though the data in buffer changes

Comment: unsigned char buffer[50*200] = {150}; QImage img(buffer, 50, 200, QImage::Format_Indexed8); m_scene->clear(); m_scene->addPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img)); m_view->update();

Comment: `unsigned char buffer[50*200] = {150}` : This call will create a buffer with the following contents `[150,0,0,0,0,0,0,....,0]` so a black image will be displayed and only the top left pixel will have a grayscale value of 150.